# How to get child vaiable without CORS error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JS function that opens a window and fetches data once the user has completed tasks in the other window. These tasks include redirects to other websites before ending up back at the localhost. However when I try to access the child window I get a CORS error. Which is odd since they are on the same website and both uses http protocol. Anyone know a way around this?

EDIT: The port name and "domain" are exactly the same:
[image]

Parent window funtion:

```
var loginPromt = window.open(url);
      var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);
      var tempCode = null

      function checkChild() {
        tempCode = loginPromt.code
        if (tempCode != null) {
          if(tempCode.length > 120){
              tempCode = loginPromt.code
              clearInterval(timer);
              alert("Now")
              loginPromt.close
              console.log(tempCode)
          }
        }
      }   
    }
```

Child window (probably not relevant) it sucessfully sets the code.

```
},
  beforeMount: function () {
      this.code = getQueryVariable("code");
      console.log(this.code)

    },
};
```

I get console log: "SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "code" on cross-origin object"

Comment: The protocol ("http" or "https"), the host name, and the port number have to match exactly.

Comment: This isn't exactly a CORS issue which is about resources (as in the "R" in URL) loading from different origins

Comment: I think you'd do better using some sort of in-page modal dialog. That would fit better with the Vue one-way data flow ethos

Comment: @Pointy See my edit.

Comment: @Phil Yes. The problem is that the first URL is to and external website. After completing tasks there. The user is redirected to "my" website again. I don't think I can open a v-modal/v-dialog with external sources?

Comment: @GustavLindström that's pretty vital information that should be included in your question

Comment: @Phil Prob right. Added now. But do you think it is the root cause of the issue? At the end of the day it is the communication between the two "localhost:8080" windows that fail.

Comment: I haven't checked but I suspect opening a remote URL locks out access to the popup `window` object. I think you might have better luck using [`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)